# open server не открывает сайт

Tags: openserver

хотел открыть сайт через open server - не открывается, решил убрать галочку `вносить изменения` в файл HOSTS, но так open server не запускается.

Что мне делать?

Comment: Запускать от имени администратора. На этот вопрос 100 раз здесь отвечали. А вообще, советую указывать больше деталей.

Comment: ну или дать права на запись в файл hosts